# Using numpy to write an array to stdout

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, stdout

What is an idiomatic way to write a Numpy 2D Array to stdout? e.g. I have an array

```
a = numpy.array([[2., 0., 0.], [0., 2., 0.], [0., 0., 4.]])

[[ 2.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  2.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  4.]]
```

That I would like outputted as:

```
2.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 2.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 4.0
```

I can do this by converting to a nested list, and then joining the list elements:

```
print( '\n'.join( [ ' '.join( [ str(e) for e in row ] ) for row in a.tolist() ] ) )
```

but would like something like:

```
a.tofile( sys.stdout )
```

(except this gives a syntax error).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

How about the following code?

```
>>> a = numpy.array([[2., 0., 0.], [0., 2., 0.], [0., 0., 4.]])
>>> numpy.savetxt(sys.stdout, a, fmt='%.4f')
1.0000 2.0000 3.0000
0.0000 2.0000 0.0000
0.0000 0.0000 4.0000
```

In Python 3+, use `numpy.savetxt(sys.stdout.buffer, ...)`.

Comment: Why `sys.stdout.buffer` should be used in python 3+ instead of `sys.stdout`?